# UX process should be under Product management or Engineering or an Independent?

Tags: usability, process, team

Can some one tell me where exactly UX team should be located in an product based company? Product Management or Engineering Team or an independent?

Comment: This depends on your company structure (although I feel that it's unlikely to be part of the Engineering team)

Answer (score 5):

More often than not, it is part of the Product Team.

however, i have worked in organizations where there are multiple product teams. And the design team was a horizontal, with certain designers dedicated to each product team.

In this case, it makes sense to have the team as independent, but still needs to roll up to a CPO or Product head.

Having the same heirarchy helps in ensuring that design for all products across all channels are consistent and have the same design methodology

Comment: In my current ecommerce company UX team works independently while still being under the roof of IT department which helps to keep track of UX stuff being  developed.
Also it helps to know what new technologies and stuff we are taking onboard and design with it in mind.

Answer (score 3):

In our setup the UX team sits under product management, which is right next to the engineering team. whether or not this is the optimum setup would be tough to argue.

Working directly with developers tends to put boundaries on what is technically possible. While they maybe valid, developers are frequently throwing out limitations would have a gradual paralysis effect. this depends on the team culture and the capabilities of the developers as well.

When working with product managers who are assigned to various parts of the product, there might be a tendency to approach designers with specific solutions already in mind rather than problems or requirements.

While it is functionally required to work with engineer and product managers and there will be overlapping skillsets and responsibilities, personally i'm more in favour of UX being more independent and more in touch with the **USERS**.